# Can we write XSD schema for complex element that contain other element and attributes and text (all of them)?

Tags: xsd, schema, complextype

I have an XML element which contains other elements, attributes as well as text too. A sample XML data is here:

```
<property readonly="0" eraseable="1" >
    <property readonly="0" eraseable="1" >
        <property readonly="0" eraseable="1" >windows XP unknown SP unknown (Build unknown)</property>
        <property readonly="0" eraseable="1" >Windows 5.1</property>
    </property>
</property>
```

I want to define XSD schema for the element. I tried adding SimpleContent to ComplexType but I get error on validation. Here is the schema I am trying:

```
<xs:element name="property">
    <xs:complexType >
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string"/>
        </xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="property" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" use="optional" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:attribute name="readonly" use="required" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:attribute name="eraseable" use="required" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The error that I get on validation is:

*The content of '#AnonType_property' is invalid.  Element 'sequence' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.*

If I remove the `<xs:simpleContent>` from schema definition, I get error as:

*Element 'property' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.*

How do I write the schema for such element?

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
<xs:element name="property">
   <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="property"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="eraseable" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="readonly" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: The "mixed" attribute turns on some crazy texts in the elements :) I know. But problem is that it does not restrict the text to between the element start-end tags. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you use visual studio to generate the schema from your XML snippet you get this:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="property">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="property">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="property">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute name="readonly" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                      <xs:attribute name="eraseable" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="readonly" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="eraseable" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="readonly" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="eraseable" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Yeah, because its only considering the one example case. The <property> element can be nested any number of times so I don't want to hard code that. Also, at any nesting level, the element can have text. Essentially, the element is same at any level and text is optional.

Comment: OK I see what you wanted to do now. Sorry for the stupid post.

Comment: However you cannot mix simple and complex content in a single element. So maybe you should think about hard coding your to most likely instance documents.